# PostgreSQL - 100 million records transfer from archive to a new table

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-performance, amazon-aurora

I have a requirement to transfer data from 2 tables (**Table A** and **Table B**) into a new table.
I am using a query to join both A and B tables using an ID column.
Table A and B are archive tables without any indexes. (Millions of records)
Table X and Y are a replica of A and B with good indexes. (Some thousands of records)

Below is the code for my project.

```sql
with data as 
(
  SELECT a.*, b.* FROM A_archive a
    join B_archive b where a.transaction_id = b.transaction_id
  UNION 
  SELECT x.*, y.* FROM X x 
    join Y y where x.transaction_id = y.transaction_id
 )
INSERT INTO 
Another_Table 
(
  columns
)
select * from data
On Conflict(transaction_id)
  do udpate ...
```

The above whole thing is running in production environment and has nearly 140 million records.
Due to this production database is taking almost 10 hours to process the data and failing.

I am also having a *distributed job scheduler* in AWS to schedule this query inside a function and retrieve the latest records every 5 hours. The archive tables store closed invoice data. Pega UI will be using this table for retrieving data about closed invoices and showing to the customer.

Please suggest something that is a bit more performant.

Comment: What if the same transaction will be in two tables (or even 3 if we count Another_Table starting state). What should be the order of resolving this conflict situation, which row is more important ?

Why not to have 2 insert statemens, first from X,Y and after that from A_archive and B_Archive. No need for union and cleaner order of inserting  or updating

Comment: @Kadet, The same transaction wont be in both.
But if it is there, I am eliminating that scenario using the UNION.
This is costing me so much. UNION ALL should be a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION` removes duplicate rows. On big unindexed tables that is an expensive operation.  Try `UNION ALL` if you don't need deduplication. It will save the s**tton of data shuffling and comparisons required for deduplication.

Without indexes on your archival tables your JOIN operation will be grossly inefficient. Index, at a minimum, the `transaction_id` columns you use in your ON clause.

You don't say what you want to do with the resulting table.  In many cases you'll be able to use a VIEW rather than a table for your purposes. A VIEW removes the work of creating the derived table. Actually it defers the work to the time of SELECT operations using the derived structure. If your SELECT operations have highly selective WHERE clauses the savings can be astonishing. For this to work well you may need to put appropriate indexes on your archival tables.

You use `SELECT *` when you could enumerate the columns you need. That certainly puts one redundant column into your result: it generates two copies of `transaction_id`. It also may generate other redundant or unused data. Always avoid `SELECT *` in production software unless you know you need it.

Keep this in mind: SQL is declarative, not procedural. You declare (describe) the result you require, and you let the server work out the best way to get it. VIEWs let the server do this work for you in cases like your table combination. It will use the indexes you provide as best it can.

Comment: Thanks for the response @O.Jones.
I am using the new table in Pega to showcase and filter the data based on the requirement.
I am using the column names in my `SELECT` query. I just didnot paste them all due to privacy policies in my company.

Comment: VIEWs are tables: virtual tables. Some of them can't take INSERTs or UPDATEs, otherwise they work the same throughout.

Comment: This makes sense but because I am working with almost 1400K records and VIEW kinda doesn't make sense for me to use. Not sure if it is really performant.

Answer (score 1):

That UNION must be costly, it pretty much builds a temp-table in the background containing all the `A-B` + `X-Y` records, sorts it (over all fields) and then removes any doubles. If you say 100 million records are involved then that's a LOT of sorting going on that most likely will involve swapping out to disk.

Keep in mind that you only need to do this if there are expected duplicates

- in the result from the `JOIN` between `A` and `B`
- in the result from the `JOIN` between `X` and `Y`
- in the combined result from the two above

*IF* neither of those are expected, just use `UNION ALL`
In fact, in that case, why not have 1 INSERT operation for `A-B` and another one for `X-Y`? Going by the description I'd say that whatever is in `X-Y` should overrule whatever is in `A-B` anyway, right?

Also, as mentioned by O.Jones, archive tables or not, they should come at least with a (preferably clustered) index on the `transaction_id` fields you're `JOIN`ing on. (same for the `Another_Table` btw)

All that said, processing 100M records in 1 transaction IS going to take some time, it's just a lot of data that's being moved around. But 10h does sound excessive indeed.

Comment: BTW: the `clustered` comment is more aimed at MSSQL than PG; hadn't noticed the postgresql tag.